# Word which means - "decreases the beauty "

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

If I wanted to express something adds to the beauty of a place I'd use words like: embellish, adorn, beautify, *et cetera*.

What is the word which is used to express that something decreases the beauty of the place?

Comment: I like [_mar_](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mar) for this.

Comment: You mean specifically beauty of a place, not a person, object, concept or other thing.

Comment: -1 it looks like very little research went into the making of this question. A quick search for antonyms or even googling "opposite of beautify" would've given a plethora of candidates.

Comment: Are you talking about an act or a thing? And something ugly that is added, or {damage to|removal of} something beautiful? Deliberate or unintentional?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Such near-synonyms as *mar*, *spoil*, *impair*, *disfigure*, *deface*, *detract from*, *blot*, *scar*, *ruin*, *blemish*, *mutilate*, *deform* and *blight* would all be possibilities.

Comment: my favourite: to defile. Also nice: to debase, to degrade, to de-whatever essentially.

Answer (score 29):

*Tarnish* has the added implication that object in question was bright, shiny, and beautiful to begin with.  [merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tarnish)

Comment: +1, also, *taint* (implies it had purity-related beauty before being sullied), *degrade* (implies it was in fine condition or good state of integrity before being damaged, physically or reputationally), *corrode* (similar but suggests steady damage over time rather than damage from one incident)

Answer (score 17):

I prefer to use *sully*: to damage or ruin the good quality of (something)
[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sully)

Comment: Sully was my first thought, too.

Answer (score 8):

*uglify* is commonly used, at least among programmers, as the opposite of *beautify*. It is, itself, an ugly word, and ideally would not be your first choice in any literary context; however, all the other examples given (tarnish, blight, etc.) all have further implications - e.g. *tarnish* literally means to lose brightness, while *blight* implies the subject is a plant.

I think that *mar* is probably the best word, but for pure technical precision, you can't beat *uglify*.

Comment: I don't agree blight implies a plant. Urban blight has little to do with plants.

Comment: enlaidir (French), afear (Spanish), enfear (Portuguese), imbruttire (Italian), for the ones I know: it's about time English had uglify. +1. But I must admit, I'd never heard it before.

Comment: @PatrickT Never read "Alice in Wonderland"?

Comment: @bof, I meant in real life, I've never heard anyone use it without obviously making a reference to Alice. (I'm a big fan of Alice, I was at Christ Church to visit the rabbit hole)

Comment: @PatrickT then it might just be a programmer thing. When I google "uglify" I mostly get UglifyJS, so that might be where I got it from. But, it is in the merriam-webster: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uglify

Comment: Good to know. I'll see if I can make it stick. I've not been successful at all with "doable", which draws contempt from my contemporaries. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are probably better for serious writing, but I still like Lewis Carroll's *uglification* for pure whimsy.

Comment: There's also "hit with the ugly stick", which is a modern, similarly silly expression

Comment: Lewis Carroll may have put "uglification" on the map but he doesn't own it. The online OED has citations going back to 1820 for "uglification" and 1576 for "uglify" or rather "vglyfyeth" as it was spelled and conjugated back then.

Answer (score 2):

Besmirch. To mar or sully something which once was in good state.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to other answers. Also consider *diminish*.

Comment: 'diminish' is a good suggestion, but could you edit your answer so it is more of...well... and answer rather than a casual comment?

Comment: Can you provide a definition and a source? Your answer needs more of an explanation, not just a comment on other answers followed by a one-word response to the question.

Comment: @Mitch: "_an_ [emphasis mine] answer...", yes?

Answer (score 1):

In reference to a place, "pollute" would be a possibility. My first thought was "mar", but "blemish" or "deface" are also good options.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I thought of was tainted.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. *Tainted* is not a verb, but *taint* would do.

Answer (score -2):

Lack luster. Implies at one point said object was beautiful and shiny, also could be used to compare to another object as in, "Due to your new rims, your paint job has been rendered slightly lack luster.

Comment: *Lackluster* is one word. And it is actually more about "lacking brightness, luster, or vitality; dull" http://www.wordnik.com/words/lackluster  I don't think it necessarily implies that an object was ever beautiful or shiny.

Comment: Also, it appears the questioner was looking for a verb.  I'm not certain you would convert Lackluster to a verb, but I doubt it would be elegant.